# jQuery: When button is clicked check what div is visible then do some stuff

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery:

```
$("#quiz-prev, #quiz-next").click(function () {
    $("ul.chart li").removeClass("active");

    if($("#page1:visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("1");
        $("#quiz-prev").hide();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page2:visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("2");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page3:visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("3");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page4:visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three, ul.chart li.four").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("4");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page5:visible")) {
        alert('test');
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three, ul.chart li.four, ul.chart li.five").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("5");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").hide();
    }
});

    $("#quiz-prev").click(function () {
        $(".page:visible").hide().prev().show();
    });
    $("#quiz-next").click(function () {
        $(".page:visible").hide().next().show();
    });
```

The idea is that when the prev and next buttons are pressed the code checks which div is visible and then would hide or show the buttons, hide or show the next or previous section div and add a class to a chart. However it jumps straight to the #page5 code even though it's not visible on the page... any ideas what is wrong with the code?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="page-navigation Clearfix">
                                <a id="quiz-prev" class="Prev" href="javascript:void(false);" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>Prev</span>
                                </a>
                                <a id="quiz-next" class="Next" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span>Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>

<p class="step">Step <span>1</span> / 5</p>

                            <ul class="chart Clearfix">
                                <li class="one active"></li>
                                <li class="two"></li>
                                <li class="three"></li>
                                <li class="four"></li>
                                <li class="five"></li>
                            </ul>


<div id="page1" class="page" style="display:block;">
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="page3" class="page" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="page4" class="page" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="page5" class="page" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are none of them visible at the start? This may cause bugs, as it's looking for a visible page, yet none are... although I may be wrong

Comment: They are all hidden apart from the first page. When the prev or next is clicked it will change the next or previous one to visible. Then the code checks which is visible and does the relevant jazz but only the former is working and not the latter.

Comment: Sorry, early start, missed display:block. Try   if($("#pageNUM").is(":visible")) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your javascript with this:

```
$("#quiz-prev, #quiz-next").click(function () {
    $("ul.chart li").removeClass("active");

    if($("#page1").is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("2");
        $("#quiz-prev").hide();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page2").is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("3");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page3").is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("4");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page4").is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three, ul.chart li.four").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("5");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").show();
    }
    if($("#page5").is(":visible")) {
        alert('test');
        $("ul.chart li.one, ul.chart li.two, ul.chart li.three, ul.chart li.four, ul.chart li.five").addClass("active");
        $("p.step span").html("6");
        $("#quiz-prev").show();
        $("#quiz-next").hide();
    }
});

    $("#quiz-prev").click(function () {
        $(".page:visible").hide().prev().show();
    });
    $("#quiz-next").click(function () {
        $(".page:visible").hide().next().show();
    });
```

Comment: you should have made it generic like using each, as i see a common class is used for each div. $('.page').each(function(){.... now based upon bool whether visible do your actions.

Comment: I basically adapted his code. You're right, he could of, but then he would have to do various if statements inside the each to do the different functions that he wants each command to do. He simply asked us to answer his question, not improve / change his code to a better method.

Comment: right friend just to keep him aware not to highlight your mistake...you right by providing him the answer he wanted..thanks!

Comment: No problem! it is a good observation to make the code more lightweight, effecient and generic

Answer (score 1):

Hm, try re-factoring your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/6UNrv/

Just call `SetActivePage()` when the page first loads, and keep in mind that currpage/maxpage are working off of zero-index.

edit: also, remove all your `active` and `display:none` markup in your aspx, the `SetActivePage()` will take care of it.

```
var currpage = 0;
var maxpage = 4;

$('.Next').click(function(e) {
  currpage += (currpage==maxpage) ? 0 : 1;
  SetActivePage();
});

$('.Prev').click(function(e) {
  currpage -= (currpage==0) ? 0 : 1;
  SetActivePage();
});

function SetActivePage() {
  $('div.page').each(function(i,o) {
    $(o).toggle(i==currpage);
  });

  $('p.step span').html(currpage+1);

  $('ul.chart li').each(function(i,o) {
    $(o).toggleClass('active',i <= currpage);
  });

  $('.Next').toggle(currpage<maxpage);
  $('.Prev').toggle(currpage>0);
}
```